# Quotes on docker-compose.yml ports make any difference?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't know if there is a difference between ports with or without quotes in a `docker-compose.yml` file, can't find any good documentation.

- With quotes

```yaml
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
```

- Without quotes

```yaml
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
```

I see no difference when I run it

Comment: The YAML spec is on yaml.org.  Sometimes strings with colons can look like `key: value` mappings, and strings of digits can look like numbers when they need to be strings, so I'm in the habit of quoting them.

Comment: Just had an issue when I wanted to expose postfix port 25 in docker-compose. `"25:25"` was working, whereas `25:25` didn't. So I guess it's always a good idea to use the quotes

Comment: I got bit by this as well. `21:21` created the mapping `0.0.0.0:32769->1281/tcp`. Okay then!?

Comment: this also happens with the official postgres:13.2(13 as well) container. If you use 5433:5432 it won't expose 5433 port, and you will get connection refused. As soon as you change it to "5433:5432" it will work

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Note from Docker Compose file version 3 reference:

> When mapping ports in the HOST:CONTAINER format, you may experience erroneous results when using a container port lower than 60, because YAML parses numbers in the format xx:yy as a base-60 value. For this reason, we recommend always explicitly specifying your port mappings as strings.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports