# RabbitMQ connection timeout with dockerized application

Tags: docker, go, rabbitmq

I'm building a go app which sends a message to a RabbitMQ queue when accessing an endpoint. The problem is that, when I'm accessing this endpoint, I receive this error and the application closes.

```
2021/04/12 21:30:06 Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: dial tcp: lookup rabbitmq on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:48796->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout
```

This is how I'm connecting:

```
conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672")
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_go_net

  plant-service:
    build: . 
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_SERVER: rabbitmq
networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
```

It's possible to send messages from another non dockerized application I have, which is connected this way:

```
conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
```

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thank you

**Edit**

The problem was that rabbitmq was on a different network, here is the fixed docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq

  plant-service:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_SERVER: rabbitmq
```

Comment: First, try using quotes around all your port mappings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810789/quotes-on-docker-compose-yml-ports-make-any-difference

Comment: Is there a reason that you are putting the `rabbitmq` container on the `rabbitmq_go_net` network? (whereas the other containers are on the default network). The error you are seeing appears dns related but I'd start by putting `rabbitmq` and `plant-service` (assuming that is your go app) on the [same network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) (or all on the default network).

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you, it's working now. I'm new to Docker and Rabbit so I just copy pasted  the docker-compose from another project. I edit my post with the new docker-compose.yml