# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in a Docker-Compose App

Tags: node.js, docker, http, docker-compose, cors

I am working on a simple docker-compose app consisting of 2 containers: one containing the backend in node.js/koa and another holding the frontend in React. I have configured those as such:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - PORT=8000
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - PORT=9000
      - MAP_ENDPOINT=http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5
      - TARGET_CITY=Helsinki,fi
      - APPID=api_key_here
```

backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My app is using kcors:

```
const cors = require('kcors');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));
```

Which should allow cross origin requests.

The frontend of my application is supposed to fetch some data from the backend:

```
const getWeatherFromApi = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://backend:9000/api/weather');
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return {};
};
```

However, as says the tile, I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:9000/api/weather. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

The network tab in my browser (Firefox) shows:
[Request in the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y86BB.png)

I confirmed that the two containers can talk to each other by pinging one another directly from within the containers:

```
docker exec -it frontend bash
root@e87994510b0e:/app# ping backend
PING backend (172.25.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
```

I also tried the following:

```
root@e87994510b0e:/app# curl http://backend:9000/api/weather
{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}root@e87994510b0e:/app#
```

Which produces the expected result. It does not however work in the browser. I am fairly new to this, quite lost and overthinking this alot. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it does @Phil, and to say I am embarrassed right now would be a big understatement. Thank you!

Comment: No problem and it's a very common mistake so no need to be embarrassed. FYI, you should quote your port mappings, ie `"9000:9000"`. [YAML is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743942/283366)

Comment: Oh, I see, will do so from now on. Thank you once again @Phil!

Comment: @tranzzik: I don't see Phil's original comment: what was the problem, and how did you fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @ShafiqueJamal Hello, what I changed was I called my backend by the 'http://localhost:9000/api/weather' address instead of 'http://backend:9000/api/weather'. The frontend was sending the request through the browser on my host PC, and it has no clue what 'backend:9000' is. I had the same problem while trying to deploy this app to Azure, this time though 'localhost' was not the answer, as it was looking for the api on the users machine, lol. This I solved by separating the two containers into two different web apps on Azure. There likely is a better way, but I am new to this and don't rly know.